# Filter the data array by onChange an input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below, I am trying to run `onChange={this.handleChange}` with react js.I would like to obtain the items by filtering them based on what is written on Input,I tried the following :

```
<input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

handleChange= evt =>
        this.setState(
            {
                name: evt.target.value.toLowerCase()
            },
            () => {
               .
               .
               .
            }
        )
```

Firstly there is an input and the its function that return the value of the input.

```
const data=[
  { "info": [{ "name": "ali" }, { "name": "amir" }, { "name": "maya" }] },
  { "info": [{ "name": "eli" }, { "name": "mary" }] },
  { "info": [{ "name": "ali" }] },
  {
    "info": [{ "name": "emila" }, { "name": "alex" }, { "name": "sosan" }]
  }
]

data = data .filter(item => {
  if (this.renderName(item).some((r) => {
        r.includes(name)
    }
   )) return item;
})

renderName(element){
  let elementAdd = []
       for (let i = 1; i <  element.info.length; i++) {
            elementAdd.push(element.info[i].name.toLowerCase())
        }
        return elementAdd
    }
```

And I want to filter the data array based on input value, but it does not work!

**Edit:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, info: [{ name: "ali" }, { name: "amir" }, { name: "maya" }] },
        { id: 2, info: [{ name: "eli" }, { name: "mary" }] },
        { id: 3, info: [{ name: "mary" }] },
        {
          id: 4,
          info: [{ name: "emila" }, { name: "alex" }, { name: "sosan" }],
        },
      ],
      name: "",
    };
  }

  reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { name } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    if (name !== "") {
      library = library.filter((item) => {
        if (
          this.renderName(item).some((r) => {
            name.includes(r);
          })
        )
          return item;
      });
    }
  };
  renderName(element) {
    let elementAdd = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < element.info.length; i++) {
      elementAdd.push(element.info[i].name.toLowerCase());
    }
    return elementAdd;
  }

  handleChange = (evt) =>
    this.setState(
      {
        name: evt.target.value.toLowerCase(),
      },
      () => {
        this.reorganiseLibrary();
      }
    );

  renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.map((item) => <div className="item">{item.id}</div>);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        {this.renderLibrary()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App></App>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code and I will only discuss the critical points.

reorganiseLibrary method

- data not extracted from props

handleChange method

- wrong use of setState. No second parameter as far as I know.

renderName method

- you only get name property but you expect an object in renderLibrary method

Here is a solution that I can think of.

```
state = {
   data: [],
   name: "",
   library: [] // use this to show latest filtered data
}

function onChange(event) {

  const { data} = this.state;

  this.setState(
  {
    name: event.target.value.toLowerCase()
  });

  let filteredResult = [];
  for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    var filteredValue = data[index].info.filter(item => item.name.includes(event.target.value));
    if(filteredValue.length != 0)
      filteredResult.push(filteredValue);
  }

  if(filteredResult.length != 0) // remove this if you want to reset the display in your UI
     setState({library : filteredResult}); 
}

renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (library.length > 0)) {
       return library.foreach(item => (<div className="item">{item.id}</div>)); // modify the onChange filter if you want the outer object        
};
```

Comment: Thanks @jtabuloc for your answer, but could you please tell me what is wrong with the code that I wrote?

Comment: I assumed the data array variable got overwritten. If you could show complete code of your component, I could point other contributors to your issue. But does it solved your problem?

Comment: I added some new code to show my component. Your code was good but I really want to find the problem of my code.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope it will help. I recommend you read the official react document.